# Error in serverless framework with azure with node js in .YML file

Tags: node.js, serverless-framework

I wanted to setup my project with azure with serverless framework but it gives an error in .YML file

Value is not accepted. Valid values: "aws"

But I want to use azure. It is not even running locally

Here is my .yml code

service: azure-nodejs

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
name: azure// error occur here of (Value is not accepted. Valid values: "aws".)
region: West US 2
runtime: nodejs12

Comment: Hello, could you share your full service devinition? If you want to use `azure`, you need to use `serverless-azure-functions `plugin

Comment: service: azure-nodejs

frameworkVersion: '3'
provider:
  name: azure
  region: West US 2
  runtime: nodejs12
  environment:
    VARIABLE_FOO: 'foo'

plugins: 
  - serverless-azure-functions
package:
  patterns:
  
    - '!local.settings.json'
    - '!.vscode/**'
functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/handlers/hello.sayHello
    events:
      - http: true
        methods:
          - GET
        authLevel: anonymous

  goodbye:
    handler: src/handlers/goodbye.sayGoodbye
    events:
      - http: true
        methods:
          - GET
        authLevel: anonymous

Comment: functions are running properly but error in .yml file. I'm try to solve it from 2 days but I can't might be there is an issue of my editor vscode